# Can SSIS create output spreadsheet based on value of field in Input

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

A department in my company gets a report every day as a a spreadsheet of invalid debit cards. It can contain 0 to hundreds of different clients. The client ID is a column on the spreadsheet. They have to take the records for Client A, make a spreadsheet called, say Client_A_20170602.xlsx and email that to client A. Then they have to do the same for client B. If there are just a few clients then it is not a big deal to do it manually, but today they had 115 different clients. They want to know if I can write an SSIS package that will automate this process.

I could bring the spreadsheet into an SQL table, do a SELECT DISTINCT on the Client ID, put the results into a temp table, go through each client on the temp table, get their records, and put them into a date stamped table. I could then (back in SSIS) use a FOR EACH loop to look for files that contain the date stamp and write them out to spreadsheets.

Can this work? Can somebody suggest a better solution?

Thanks,

Dick

Comment: Yes, this is doable in SSIS.  Question.  Do you need SSIS to send the email?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be an SSRS Report with each client getting a subscription that emails them their data.